# Command "web mvc geo controller..." on Spring Roo not Running

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

I have been experimenting with Spring Roo lately and was interested in seeing how to build GeoApplications with the gvnix roo addon. I am following the tutorial found [here](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-geo-app).

I follow all the steps, but when I reach the section for "Generate Map View" roo seems to not respond to the command given in the tutorial. Am using Postgres 9.3, gvNIX 1.5.1.RC4 distribution 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8]. My log.roo is as follows:

```
    project --topLevelPackage com.petclinic --projectName petclinic --java 7 --packaging JAR
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2016-01-06 22:04:30
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2016-01-06 22:05:34

osgi start --url file:////home/tumaini/.m2/repository/postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901-1.jdbc4/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar

jpa setup --database POSTGRES --provider HIBERNATE --databaseName petclinic --hostName localhost --userName postgres --password jej3bimt
database introspect --schema public
database reverse engineer --schema public --package ~.domain
jpa geo setup --provider HIBERNATE_SPATIAL
field geo --fieldName location --type POINT --class ~.domain.Owner
field geo --fieldName distance --type LINESTRING --class ~.domain.Owner
field geo --fieldName area --type POLYGON --class ~.domain.Owner
finder geo all
web mvc geo controller --class ~.web.MapViewerController --preferredMapping mapview --projection EPSG4326
```

It is on this last roo command where I get the error

```
Command 'web mvc geo controller --class ~.web.MapViewerController --preferredMapping mapview --projection EPSG4326' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
~.domain.Owner roo-gvNIX>
```

The postgres database (a very small one for tutorials purpose) can be restored from the backup file found at http://github.com/kilimba/tmarc/blob/master/petclinic.backup.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since gvNIX 1.5 geo views use the fancytree addon of gvNIX for showing the TOC. Before using command `web mvc geo controller` you need to use `web mvc fancytree setup` to install that TOC dependency.

That dependency is described in [gvNIX reference guide](http://www.gvnix.org/assets/doc/gvnix-1.5.1.RC4-reference-docs.pdf), but not in the [quickstart guide](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-geo-app) which you are following, so **it should be updated**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try that out and update this thread accordingly. By the way, the reference guide for gvNIX that you referred to, is there anywhere I can get an english version?

Comment: Validate the answer if it works for you. Thanks for the support to gvNIX project.

Comment: Tumaini, thanks to Curt Huffman (https://github.com/Cujo13) there is an alpha version of the documentation in english. You can download it from https://github.com/gvSIGAssociation/gvnix/issues/23